# using correlated subquery in the case statement

Tags: sql

I’m trying to use a correlated subquery in my sql code and I can't wrap my head around what I'm doing wrong. A brief description about the code and what I'm trying to do:

The code consists of a big query  (ALIASED AS A) which result set looks like a list of customer IDs, offer IDs and response status name ("SOLD","SELLING","IRRELEVANT","NO ANSWER" etc.) of each customer to each offer. The customers IDs and the responses in the result set are non-unique, since more than one offer can be made to each customer, and a customer can have different response for different offers.

The goal is to generate a list of distinct customer IDs and to mark each ID with 0 or 1 flag :
 if the ID has AT LEAST ONE  offer with status name is "SOLD" or "SELLING" the flag should be 1 otherwise 0. Since each customer has an array of different responses, what I'm trying to do is to check if "SOLD" or "SELLING" appears in this array for each customer ID, using  correlated subquery in the case statement and aliasing the big underlying query  named A with A1 this time:

```
select distinct
A.customer_ID,

case when 'SOLD' in  (select distinct A1.response from A  as A1
                        where A.customer_ID = A1.customer_ID) OR

          'SELLING' in (select distinct A1.response from A  as A1
                        where A.customer_ID = A1.customer_ID) 

           then 1 else 0 end as FLAG
FROM
(select …) A
```

What I get is a mistake alert saying there is no such object as A or A1.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Please tag you DB, post some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Minimize - [mcve].

Comment: You cannot select from alias.Yo have to select from actual table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists` with `cte` :

```
with cte as (
     <query here> 
)
select c.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 
                          from cte c1 
                          where c1.customer_ID = c.customer_ID and 
                                c1.response in ('sold', 'selling')
                         )
             then 1 else 0 
        end) as flag
from cte c;
```

You can also do aggregation :

```
select customer_id, 
       max(case when a.response in ('sold', 'selling') then 1 else 0 end) as flag
from < query here > a;
group by customer_id;
```

Comment: @Mar . . . From your description of the problem, the aggregation approach is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

With statement as suggested by Yogesh is a good option. If you have any performance issues with "WITH" statement. you can create a volatile table and use columns from volatile table in your select statement .

1. create voltaile table as (select response from  where response in ('SOLD','SELLING').
2. SELECT  from customer table < and join voltaile table>.

The only disadvantge here is volatile tables cannot be accessed after you disconnect from session.